# Struggling with finding a potential counterexample for a convergent series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

This question comes with two parts.

Part (a): Let $\{f_n(x)\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative functions for $x \in S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1 \geq f_2 \geq \dots \geq 0$, and that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $S$. Prove that

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n - 1}f_n(x)$$

converges uniformly on $S$.

Part (b): Use part (a) to determine if

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n - 1}}{\sqrt{n(n + x)}}$$

converges uniformly on $(0, \infty)$.

I was able to prove part (a). I am getting stuck on part (b). I think the sequence of functions in part (b) only converges pointwise, but I am struggling with this proof. The proof would be a lot simple if $x = 0$, but it cannot be. Do I do something with infimum's here?

Comment: Some details. I keep getting that $$x > (1/\epsilon^2 - n^2)/n,$$ and I am not sure if this is the right track.

Comment: I mean, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+nx}}$ is still uniformly bounded by $\frac{1}{n}$ for $x\in (0,\infty).$

Comment: DUH. Man, I feel dumb right now, lmfao. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, you had it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the other conditions apply trivially, you just need to check that $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+x)}}$ converges uniformly to $0$ in $(0,\infty)$. Just note that

$$
\sup_{x >0} \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+x)}} \right| \leq \frac{1}{n} \to 0\quad(n \ \to \infty)
$$

Comment: Well, you also need to at least mention $f_1 \geq f_2 \geq \dots \geq 0$

Comment: @zhw Sure, the question was specifically  about the uniform convergence but for the sake of completeness I'll edit the post.